# how do I loop through an arraylist of winforms?

Tags: arrays, winforms, arraylist

I am currently developing a windows form application and I have a arraylist notificationList that contains notificationForms.

How do I use a for loop to loop through every single form in the arrayList to check if the forms are disposed through the isDisposed property?

```
int formDisposed = 0;  

for (int i = 0; i < notificationList.Count; i++)
{
    if(notificationList.?????.IsDisposed == true)
    {
      formDisposed ++;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put the horse before the wagon.  When you create the form, subscribe its FormClosed event and have the event handler remove the form object from the list.  Solves this problem and avoids the nasty memory leak.

Comment: if i do it this way, how do i search through the list and delete the form such that it is the particular form that i have closed?

Comment: Use the event's *sender* argument.  It's a reference to the form that got closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually by using

```
if(notificationList[i].IsDisposed)
```

if for some reason you don't have this option: add the following line to your .cs file

```
using System.Data;
```

and Syste.Data and Syste.Data.DataSetExtensions so you will able to access xxx.ElementAt(i) method.

You can also use foreach:

```
int formDisposed = 0;  

foreach (Form f in notificationList)
{
    if(f.IsDisposed)
      formDisposed ++;
}
```

Comment: you can also try to do this with Linq

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists are indexable with square brackets (notificationList[i]), but this isn't going to work without a cast to your type. ArrayList returns the type Object and Object does not implement IsDisposed. You may want to consider using a Generic List of Controls (List<Control>) instead, which would work the same but not need a cast.